# Modx Revo Wayfinder: Add extra attribute to list item of current menu

Tags: modx

Ref: Wayfinder on Modx Revo

I've been searching extensively and couldn't find the answer.

I find a very tricky situation trying to output an extra attribute with the list item that wraps the current menu (the menu link on of the page you're currently in). 
For example:
Instead of just this line..

```
<li class="current"><a href="#">This is the menu</a></li>
```

I want..

```
<li class="current" value="1"><a href="#">This is the menu</a></li>
```

see **value="1"**

I tried creating a chunk in relation with the &hereTpl parameter but apparently this parameter is no longer valid in Wayfinder Revo (or is it?).

I think another possible route is if there's a way for a conditional inside the &rowTpl to render the needed attribute only for the current menu but again another brick wall.

I also tried the [[+wf.attributes]] (on the list item tag in the template chunk and put the needed attribute in the Link attributes of all the the resources/documents assuming it's going to render only when the resource/document is "current" but then the attribute is just outputted to all the menu items.

Could you share a thought? thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/splittingred/Wayfinder/blob/develop/core/components/wayfinder/wayfinder.class.php) and [documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Wayfinder#Wayfinder-TemplateParameters), `hereTpl` is indeed still valid

Comment: Hi thanks. I did use &hereTpl=`myTpl` but seems like it's not parsing. I'll re-check. Thx for the feedback I really appreciate.

Comment: I can't figure a way to put the back tick sign.. but you know what I mean.. thx @Phil

Comment: I should've included the call to wayfinder I am using.. `[[Wayfinder? &startId=10 &level=1 &hereTpl=navHere &levelClass=level &outerTpl=navOuter &firstClass=first &lastClass=last &sortBy=menuindex &sortOrder=ASC &titleOfLinks=longtitle]]`

Answer (score 0):

do the following:

```
[[Wayfinder? &hereTpl=`navHere` (INCLUDE OTHER PARAMETERS THAT YOU LIKE)]]
```

In the **navHere** tpl write the following piece of code:

```
<li class="current" value="1"><a href="[[+wf.link]]">[[+wf.linktext]]</a></li>[[+wf.wrapper]]
```

I understand this would work out. Hope to get a response from you.

Comment: Hi thanks @sandip-agarwal for the advice.. I tried but still didn't work. Must be something wrong with my setup because I am also sure &hereTpl will just work. Anyways, I have resorted to different markup because deadline can't wait :D I will sure try again later to confirm everything .thanks

Comment: You are welcomed, Rix. Yes, u could try re-installing the `Wayfinder` component. And moreover, you could have a look at the `Wayfinder` snippet code.